# Как обернуть данные на выходе в два тега?

Tags: javascript

Как обернуть данные на выходе в два тега?
Сейчас вот так:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">test</div>
```

а надо, вот так

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
 <p class="data">test</p>
</div>
```

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', handler);

function handler() {
   var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
      var newEl = document.createElement('div');
      newEl.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-12');
      //***
        
      var content = document.createTextNode(data);
      newEl.appendChild(content);
      var position = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
      position.appendChild(newEl);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<textarea name="" id="data" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях удобно использовать метод [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit'),
    dataEl = document.getElementById('data'),
    targetEl = document.querySelector('.container');

submit.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (!targetEl || !dataEl || !dataEl.value.length)
    return;
  targetEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p class="data">${dataEl.value}</p>
    </div>
  `);
});
```

```css
#data { height: 50px; }

.col-sm-12, 
.data {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px; padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.col-sm-12:before,
.data:before {
  font: 10px monospace; color: #777;
}
.col-sm-12:before { content: '.col-sm-12'; }
.data:before      { content: '.data'; padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<textarea name="" id="data" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Отправить</button><br>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание: в отличие от `createElement()`, метод `insertAdjacentHTML()` **не возвращает ссылок на новые элементы**.

Но Вы можете выбрать элементы после их добавления, используя любой из предназначенных для этого методов (например, `querySelector()`).

Comment: if (!targetEl || !dataEl || !dataEl.value.length) - эта строка проверяет на существование переменных и заполненность textarea. Можете пояснить как работает?

Comment: Подвыражения разделенные оператором логического ИЛИ (`||`) выполняются последовательно, слева направо. Каждое из них с оператором логического отрицания `!`, которое инвертирует булевое значение. При этом, операнд оператора `!` автоматически приводится к булевому значению. Таким образом, если значение первых двух переменных `undefined` или `null`, оно будет приведено к `false`, а так как `!false === true`, условие выполнится (и сработает `return`). С третьим подвыражением все то же самое, только тут длина, тип `Number` - это значение проверяется на ноль: `0 === false`, а значит `!0 === true`.

Comment: Это просто понимается, если прочитать как "если НЕ[т] `targetEl` ИЛИ НЕ[т] `dataEl` ИЛИ НЕ[т] длины значения" :))

Comment: Для возврата значения используется директива return. Несколько не понятно для чего она в коде, если она ничего не возвращает, то есть нет записи типа return i; , то зачем она там?

Comment: @ikar, оператор `return` выполняет возврат из функции. В данном случае, если что-то не так с данными которые необходимы обработчику - он завершает свое выполнение. Возвращать какое-либо значение тут нет необходимости.

Comment: Это просто более "красивый" способ, чем помещение основной логики в тело `if`: в коде меньше вложенных отступов, очевидная последовательность выполнения - все это повышает читаемость.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```js
let divEl = document.createElement('div')
let pEl = document.createElement('p')
let resultEl = document.querySelector('#result')

divEl.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-12');
pEl.setAttribute('class', 'data');

pEl.append('test')
divEl.append(pEl)
resultEl.append(divEl)
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```